# Query or Limit parameter for vimeo Rest API

Tags: api, rest, parameters, limit, vimeo

I have integrated vimeo Rest API for my web application, whenever I call rest api, it return large response data, but to optimize large data, I would like to limit data to return me after particular date, and I want query data like "since=date" or "since=id", so should return me data available after this date or id, by applying query parameter to rest api, I want filter result on the basis of id or date, so please let me know, is there any way available for that.

example url is here:
https://api.vimeo.com/groups/330134/users?sort=date&direction=desc
but want like this
https://api.vimeo.com/groups/330134/users?since=2015-06-15;

Answer (score 0):

All data filters are described in the endpoint. You can reduce the fields you receive with the field filter: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter